# Setting iOS Menu Bar Color

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

When working with an air 3. 6 for iOS file, is there anyway to set the color of the top status bar on the iPhone (where the time, battery, carrier, etc is shown)? Some apps have a black bar, others have white, blue, and so on....

Comment: The status bar is not part of the AIR app so it certainly cant be done with ActionScript. Maybe an ANE could do it?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, but it doesn't work (so don't accept it as the right answer;)

I put these keys in the (application)-app.xml file, in the iPhone/InfoAdditions segment. These settings produce a yellowish status bar when used the plist of an XCode iOS project. But apparently this information doesn't end up in the application itself after being packaged into an AIR 3.8 app. Maybe this information will help you find a real solution though.

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
<key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
<dict>
    <key>UINavigationBar</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Style</key>
        <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
        <key>TintColor</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Blue</key>
            <real>0.041336614638566971</real>
            <key>Green</key>
            <real>0.89705467224121094</real>
            <key>Red</key>
            <real>0.998149573802948</real>
        </dict>
        <key>Translucent</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove from the screen using Full Screen mode, but there is no way to change the collor. Apple won't accept any software that change the status bar. that only works on jailbreak devices.

Comment: -1: Obviously that's not true. Even the question mentions different colored status bars in existing apps.